# Subtracting of TWO DATES and also subtract if Hitted Lunch break

Tags: php

```
function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime){
   $firstTime=strtotime($firstTime);
   $lastTime=strtotime($lastTime);

   $timeDiff=$lastTime-$firstTime;

   return $timeDiff;
}


$fromDate = "2013-11-15 09:00:00";
$toDate = "2013-11-15 18:00:00";

$difference = timeDiff($fromDate,$toDate);
```

now I got it's subtracted value in seconds, I alreadt converted it to time, my question is
how do I auto subtract a lunch break if my chosen lunchtime is between $fromDate and $toDate.

for example.

```
lunch is 12pm to 1pm;

$fromDate = "2013-11-15 09:00:00";
$toDate = "2013-11-15 18:00:00";
```

Im getting 9 hours here but I just need 8 because it Hitted the lunch break or lunch break is between my selected $fromDate and $toDate.

Any help Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fromDate = "2013-11-15 09:00:00";
$toDate = "2013-11-15 12:00:00";

$difference = timeDiff($fromDate,$toDate);
echo $difference;

function timeDiff($firstTime,$lastTime){

    $datetime1 = new DateTime($firstTime);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($lastTime);

    $lunchtime = new DateTime('2013-11-15 12:00:00');

  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  if($datetime2 > $lunchtime)
  {
      $real_interval=$interval->h;
      $real_interval=$real_interval-1;

  }
  else
  $real_interval=$interval->h;

   return $real_interval;
}
```

Comment: hello sir, may I know what does the $interval->h; means?

Comment: $interval->h; means hour

Comment: Thank you sir, it really help me, but what if on 2 different days

Comment: $fromDate = "2013-11-15 09:00:00";
$toDate = "2013-11-16 18:00:00";

Comment: echo $interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds";

Comment: for different date you need to check $interval->d also

Comment: i cant do it sir, can you show it to me how to add           $fromDate = "2013-11-11 09:00:00";
$toDate = "2013-11-15 18:00:00"; it will minus every time it hitted the 12:00:00 of each day

Comment: hi sir zahidul why ->h always returning positive values i.e (2-5) = 3, it must be - 3, do you have references of this code of oop so i can review, thanks in advance

Comment: It always return positive values because it calculate the difference only. check date_diff php manual for more information